# How to convert double to REFERENCE_TIME in c++?

Tags: c++, windows

```
typedef LONGLONG REFERENCE_TIME;
```

I want to convert `double Time` to `REFERENCE_TIME Time`, how to do it?

Comment: What units are your 'double Time' in?

Comment: And what units are REFERENCE_TIME in?  What time is 0 in either?

Answer (score 4):

Reference time is absed on a 100ns clock.  That means there are 10,000,000 ticks a second.

So assuming your double is in seconds then you need to do

```
REFERENCE_TIME rt = static_cast< REFERENCE_TIME >( doubleTime * 10000000.0 );
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming LONGLONG is just a typedef for a built in type, you can try:

```
REFERENCE_TIME rt = static_cast<REFERENCE_TIME>(Time);
```

But, it would be safer to use boost::numeric_cast

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/numeric/conversion/doc/html/boost_numericconversion/improved_numeric_cast__.html